# Function pointer of a member function of the current instance

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to get the function pointer of a member function of the current instance of a C++ class. Then I want to add that function pointer to a global registry.

I can't create the instance in a separate location and add the function pointer there. It should get added within this instance.

This is what I have done. But it doesn't work as intended. Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Example

In MyClass.h

```
class MyClass
{
 public:
   MyClass();
   ~MyClass();
   typedef int (MyClass::*fpointer)(int);
   int foo(int val);


private:
   void addFuncPointer();

}
```

In MyClass.cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
  addFuncPointer();
}

int MyClass::foo(int val)
{
 // Function Definition
}

void MyClass::addFuncPointer()
{
 fpointer funct = &MyClass::foo;
 //I am adding this function pointer to a global registry.
 GlobalRegistry.add(globalindex, funct);
 globalindex++;
}
```

In Main.cpp

```
int main()
{
  MyClass* cls = new MyClass();
  GlobalRegistry.getFunctionPointer(validindex)->call();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any more info on what "doesn't work as intended"?

Comment: @Steeve By using the registry I should be able to call the function within the instance from somewhere else.

Comment: @Will_Panda So what happens now if you call it?

Comment: @Steeve The callback doesn't happen.

Comment: @jxh The instance is created somewhere else. The method should bind its current instance's function.

Comment: @Will_Panda create a [mcve]

Comment: @Will_Panda No, it can't bind the current instance to the function ptr. You will have to save `this` to your registry and call the function on that object.

Comment: You have a conceptual misunderstanding: A member function is not part of an instance, it is part of a class. And invocation of a member function requires *two* ingredients, the member function *and* an instance of the class.

Comment: @user2079303 I have changed the code to make it more comprehensive.

Comment: @jxh it calls the function pointer in the index with necessary arguments.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/2130/pointers-to-members/6996/pointers-to-member-functions#t=20170223111648927392

Comment: You probably want `std::function` with `std::bind`or lambda.

Comment: @Steeve I thought that I could bind the function pointer to current instance. I think I am wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: @Will_Panda Look up what Jarod42 says in their comment, it will help you implement it this way.

Comment: Thank you. I have missed a fundamental part of calling the functor it seems. Using a function globally or passing the instance would be my solution.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you. I will try and see if it fits my requirement.

Comment: @Will_Panda `GlobalRegistry` isn't defined, and there are typos. The example isn't verifiable nor complete. Also " But it doesn't work as intended" is not useful. How does it work, and how does it differ from what you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are experiencing is caused by the fact that all objects of a class share the same code for their member functions. So if you want to invoke a member function for a particular instance, you're gonna need to save both, a pointer to the instance and a pointer to the member function.

Since C++11 this can be wrapped into a function object:

```
struct Foo {
  void func() { /* ... */ }
} foo;
auto mem_func = std::bind(&Foo::func, &foo);
mem_func();
```